# Communicating with a driver over a network in Windows

Tags: communication, driver, named-pipes, usermode

How could I communicate with a driver from a usermode application over a network? I can't have the driver communicate with a local usermode application which then communicates with the remote application because that wouldn't work for what I'm doing. I was thinking of using named pipes but I'm not sure if that would work over a network.

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes work over a network. Also you can use [TDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819740.aspx).